# When I should upload files directly to amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3

I've seen many posts talking about direct uploading to amazon S3 but none of them tell when we should really do that !

Is "direct upload to S3" always better than uploading to S3 via Rails app using gems like paperclip or carrierwave... ?

And when I should use *direct upload* vs *normal upload* to S3 ?

Comment: "direct upload" vs "normal upload" isn't a well-defined concept.  Those aren't terms I would use, since they are too vague... but I would assume they are referring to user uploads, and allowing the *browser* to upload directly to S3, instead of uploading to your server and then your server uploading the file to S3.  Does that fit the context of whatever you are reading?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes I am talkin about that exactly (user uploads), but I am just not sure what's the best approach !! if browser direct upload to S3 will reduce things like bandwidth and cpu like John says in his answer, so why should I upload to server ? I am just confusing ..

Answer (score 0):

Uploading directly to Amazon S3 has the benefit of reducing load on your back-end web servers (for both CPU and bandwidth).

It is great for mobile apps that can call the Amazon S3 API directly, but is also applicable to web pages that can upload via a POST to Amazon S3.

Comment: So should I always upload directly to Amazon S3 because I will get those benefits  ? also I would like to know what most people use for their application !